# Passing a full-text search parameter using Dapper.net

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, dapper

Consider this simple query which use full text searching on the `Keywords` field:

```
DECLARE @searchTerm VARCHAR(500) = 'painted'
SELECT * FROM StockCatalogueItems
WHERE (CONTAINS(KeyWords, @searchTerm))
```

This works as expected, but I need to do the same using a Dapper.net parameterised query.  When using stored procedures, I create the full text parameter like this: `"\"painted*\""`

But using the same approach this doesn't work using dapper. No results are returned.  This is the line in the query where I use the parameter:

```
AND (CONTAINS(KeyWords, @search))
```

and it's passed to the query like so:

```
return _context.Database.Connection.Query<StockProfileMatrix>(basequery, new
{
    search = searchTerm
}
```

I can only assume that dapper is sanitising the string somehow, removing quotes perhaps?

Any ideas?

Comment: Dapper doesn't sanitize *anything* - it uses parameters. Anything that works in TSQL using a variable *should* also work as a parameter. The only noticeable difference is that dapper defaults to unicode (`nvarchar`). Other than that, if `searchTerm` was (in C# terms) the string `"painted"`, it would be *identical* to your TSQL at the top, and should work fine. In TSQL terms, does your top query work with `DECLARE @searchTerm NVARCHAR(500) = N'painted'` ? Note: if the *term* you are after is `painted*`, then in C# terms that is just `"painted*"`, not `"\"painted*\""`

Comment: @marpsmith - I am running into the same thing, did you find the pattern? cause when I do `where contains (@name,'campb')` it *returns nothing on both sql and dapper* which is *consistent* but when I do `where contains (@name,'"campb"')` *on sql returns rows but nothing on dapper* -- any input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I'll answer the question.  The query syntax is correct, but the way in which the full-text parameter is created was obviously not.  I created an extension method that formats the parameter:

```
 public static string ToFullText(this string str)
 {
      string searchTerm = null;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
      {
          string[] keywords = str.Trim().Split(null);
          foreach (var keyword in keywords)
          {
             searchTerm += string.Format("\"{0}*\" AND ", keyword);
           }
           if (searchTerm != null)
              searchTerm = searchTerm.Substring(0, searchTerm.LastIndexOf(" AND "));
        }
        return searchTerm;
  }
```

Then I call the method when I pass the parameter in to the dapper query:

```
_context.Database.Connection.Query<dynamic>(query, new 
{ 
    search = filter.SearchTerm.ToFullText()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. However the tech stack am working on is `.net core RTM` and `"Dapper": "1.50.0-rc3"`,

```
_dbConnection.QueryAsync<Guid>(@"select br.Id from Brand br where CONTAINS(br.Text,@Name)",new {Name = $"\"*{name}*\""}))
```

Comment: Full Text Search will ignore your preceding asterisk won't it? It can only search by prefix. i.e. CONTAINS(Text, '"foo*"') and not CONTAINS(Text, '"\*foo*"').